# Is it possible to implement drag-select with React-dnd?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dnd

https://github.com/JeremyDurnell/react-drag-select

I looked at this repository, but then when I ran the demo, I noticed it just renders the selection rectangle without allowing me to select elements inside of a rectangle.

Question is, is there a way to allow users to select multiple elements with drag-select in React-DnD? I looked at the documentation and there's nothing about this.

https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/about

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with `react-dnd` by itself. Something like react-dnd-multiple-selection (https://github.com/znwang25/react-dnd-multiple-selection) might be closer to what you're looking for.

Comment: It doesn't support drag-select at all. https://angularscript.com/drag-select-component-angular-5/